# Why can't I break bedrock on my Spigot server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

This is not a duplicate of "What is this block I can't break??" questions. I know all about bedrock, including the Dark Oak sapling trick and the half-slab/wither skeleton skull trick. However, these tricks are not working on the Spigot/Bukkit server that I play on. I found something called Void Guard that sounded like it might be the culprit, but the guy that runs the server said there weren't any settings for that. What settings do we need to change to allow these tricks to work?

Comment: All options you gave are/were bugs. they might have been fixed... Bedrock is supposed to be 100% unbreakable.

Comment: We're not playing snapshots. We're in version 1.7.9, and before we added Spigot (for a dynamic map which I'm not sure is worth all the trouble we've been through with this) the sapling trick worked and I made holes to the roof of the Nether with it. I've also just tried the slab and skull trick in a 1.7.9 creative world and that works as well.

Comment: Then I don't know, I'm not really following the normal minecraft development process anymore, I'm much  too deep into modpacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they patched this in Spigot builds as of January 20th.
https://github.com/SpigotMC/Spigot/commit/d8ad596ece8c5414a77271deff0314691886339a

If your only reason for using Spigot is to have a dynmap, I'd suggest switching to a Bukkit server instead. Spigot is actually just a branch off of Bukkit anyway, and it's really only useful if you have a lot of people on your server or your server is on a really slow computer. Using a regular ol' Bukkit server will allow you to load server-side plugins just as well (dynmap, Essentials, WorldEdit, etc.), and it won't have as much code interfering with the vanilla-ness.

Comment: Ok, I see. Seems like we used Spigot because Bukkit wasn't out for the then-current version of MC... Maybe we can figure something out. Thanks.

Comment: Spigot is a branch off of Bukkit, so it seems odd that you'd find a version of Spigot that you couldn't find in Bukkit-form. When you're looking at Bukkit builds, don't be afraid to use a Beta or Development build. I've used them before and they always work fine. If you're waiting for a released version of Bukkit, you could be waiting a while. :)

Answer (score 2):

A google search revealed that on the [page for the mod on Curse](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/voidguard) there was a link to the [instructions for editing the config.yml](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/voidguard/pages/config-yml/).

It says you need to set the value `prevent-bedrock-layer-break` to `false`.
Please refer to the site itself for the rest of the instructions, as it seems it is capable of keeping people out of the void areas after a hole is created.

Comment: Ok looks like this is just about Void Guard. To be clear, we aren't using that mod, or any other besides DynMap. We are just trying to get as vanilla-like behavior as possible with the spigot server.